# How to write Javascript from code behind at the end of HTML page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to write javascript from code behind but at the end of my HTML document.
With `Response.Write`, I can write at the beginning of the file but how can I write at the end or in an other place ?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: You asking about WebForms or MVC?

Comment: Why does it matters ? I use WebForms.

Comment: You should use [RegisterStartupScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/asz8zsxy.aspx).

Comment: Webforms... *shudders*

Comment: If you use Response.Write it would probably break the entire layout so your question possible duplicated of [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2574131/appending-javascript-code-piece-to-the-end-of-the-body-tag) or [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2261385/neatest-way-of-adding-javascript-to-a-page-footer-in-asp-net)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write your JS function at the bottom of the HTML document, then just call it in the page load event in code behind file with

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "Javascript", "javascript:someFunction();", true);
```